# AsyncTask creation causes crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Having some issues with a custom class that extends AsyncTask. My app is Targeting Android 4.0.3 and the below code works fine for 30+ people testing it. However there are two users that are seeing the app crash when I call new AsyncRequest like below.

I've got a working logger that is recording to a text file on the users storage and doesn't record the entry that is in the AsyncRequest constructor. So I have to assume that the crash is happening before the constructor is called.

One of the two devices that are experiencing this crash is running Android 4.0.4 apparently. Not sure what the other device is running. Unfortunately I dont' have access to the two devices so can't see a logcat output.

Any input as to why the object creation is causing a crash would be greatly appreciated.

```
String url = "www.google.com";

new AsyncRequest(callback, context).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
```

And here is the full AsyncRequest class

```
public class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

HttpURLConnection connection;
InputStream inStream;
IApiCallback callback;
Context context_;

public AsyncRequest(IApiCallback callback, Context context) {
    // Log entry added for testing. Never gets called.
    FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportInfo("Enter AsyncRequest Constructor");
    this.callback = callback;
    context_ = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri[0] + "?format=json");
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportInfo("Async Request: Sending HTTP GET to " + url);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        connection.connect();

        String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding();

        // Determine if the stream is compressed and uncompress it if needed.
        if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            inStream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        }  else {
            inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        }

        if (inStream != null) {
            // process response
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            return sb.toString();  

        }

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportException("Async Request: SocketTimeoutException", e);
        Log.i("AsyncRequest", "Socket Timeout occured");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportException("Async Request: MalformedUrlException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportException("Async Request: IOException", e);
        Log.i("doInBackground:","IOException");

        if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null) {
            Log.i("doInBackground:",e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportException("Async Request: Exception", e);

    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result != null) 
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportInfo("Async Request: Response is valid");
    else
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context_).ReportInfo("Async Request: Invalid response");

    callback.Execute(result);
}
}
```

EDIT: As per comments below.

Here is the full method that I call my custom AsyncTask from. All the logging messages I have up to creating the AsyncTask are showing in the log. None of the exceptions are.

The logging displays the url value just before creating my AsyncRequest and the URL is not malformed at all. It's what I'm expecting.

```
public void GetServerInfoAsync(IApiCallback callback, Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException, Exception {

    if (callback == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("callback");

    if (context == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("context");

    try {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportInfo("Build URL");
        String url = GetApiUrl("System/Info");
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportInfo("Finished building URL");

        if (url != null) {
            FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportInfo("GetServerInfoAsync: url is " + url);
            new AsyncRequest(callback, context).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
        } else {
            FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportError("GetServerInfoAsync: url is null");
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportException("GetServerInfoAsync: IllegalArgumentException", iae);
        throw iae;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLogger.getFileLogger(context).ReportException("GetServerInfoAsync: Exception", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: If You already found out error is before this request, show the code before You call it.

Comment: Have you put logging in the code in the run up to creating the `AsyncTask`? Perhaps this would allow you to see which line is actually failing?

Comment: Gustek. Error does not appear to be before I call it. I've appended the calling method to my original post.

Comment: Is it possible that the devices where the crash occur have lower memory available and the app is crashing due to lack of memory?

Comment: Probably offtopic, but you would want to change String to String... in onPostExecute signature

Comment: @Vasco. This method is called during the launching of the App. There is very little work done prior. If it's relevant, this is the first asynctask that is called by the app.

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the exception being thrown by the GetServerInfoAsync method? Does FileLogger use the external SD card? Do the phones have SD cards? Not much we can do but speculate from what you've given us. Do you have any information about the phones? Have you run an emulator( :-( ) in 4.0.4 to try and replicate the error?

Comment: You seem to be able to get the error log (otherwise how do you know thatthe entry within the constructor isn't logged). So why not add more device information (device type, SDK version, available memory) **and** use an `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Comment: @Wolfram. I'm embarrassed to say I didn't know about the Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. I'll be baking it into a build tomorrow and seeing what additional info it nets. I had limited device info logged already. Both devices had a few hundred megs available, and both have a memory class of 48MB per application available. One device has a screen res of 1280x752 (Acer Iconia A200). The other one is a [junker](http://www.amazon.com/Zeepad-Allwinnwer-Capacity-Multiple-Capactive/dp/B00918LE6G/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1368862631&sr=8-3&keywords=zeepad)

Comment: ok. Thanks to UncaughtExceptionHandler I've discovered that the app is throwing both java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when it tries to create my AsyncRequest. I have no idea why. [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4038856/client-c4df6647-c5ec-47f8-9760-aac49af3a164.txt) my logger entry just in case

Comment: Strange that this error only manifests itself in these two clients.

Comment: Have you tried splitting `new AsyncRequest(callback, context).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url)` into two lines to verify that it is the creation (and not the initial execution) that causes the issue: `AsyncRequest ar = new AsyncRequest(callback, context); ar.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just keep in mind that `executeOnExecutor()` is not available prior to Api 11. You have already said the issue is with a 4.0.4 device, but just keep this in mind.

Here are the steps I would take in order to troubleshoot what the problem is. It seems as if you have already done a few of these with all those `ReportInfo()` statements.

First, I assume your call to `GetServerInfoAsync` is within a `try...catch`, correct? I am checking because of your use of `Throw`. Also, you have already added logging to check for errors with the url. Since the errors occur before you actually use it, the error cannot be with the url, or any internet permissions. 
You call the AsyncTask generation with references to `callback` and `context`. You have added logging via `ReportInfo()` which references context, and those work, yes? Therefore, context is not your issue. However, you never check what `callback` is. You throw an error if it is null, but you never do anything with it before you call `AsyncRequest`. Try a `ReportInfo(callback.toString())` to see what it is.

If all else fails, it would seem to be an error with threading. Why not try using just AsyncTask, instead of `executeOnExecutor()`. Do you really need more than 1 background thread?

Comment: Thanks for reply. My min/target sdk versions are 15/17, I had tested without `ExecuteOnExecutor` with the same failure. The calling method is indeed surrounded by a try/catch. As you've suggested, the logging does work within the GetServerInfoAsync method, right up until the AsyncTask instance is created (or attempted to). After work I'll be trying Wolframs suggestion and hopefully have more concrete info for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not getting back to this sooner. There were numerous issues here.

First off... Thanks to Wolfram's suggestion I was able to catch the exception and diagnose that the issue was that my FileLogger (and another class) was a static reference and these two tablets couldn't find the reference at runtime. So I ended up removing Logging from my async methods.

Secondly, after making the above changes there was another issue which was that a looper had to be called from the main thread. It turned out that these two tablets weren't calling my async task from the main thread. So I had to enclose the async call in a new Handler using the MainLooper.